# Reading excel and storing data with xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I have this data in excel sheet

```
FT_NAME     FC_NAME C_NAME
FT_NAME1    FC1     C1
FT_NAME2    FC21    C21
            FC22    C22
FT_NAME3    FC31    C31
            FC32    C32
FT_NAME4    FC4     C4
```

where column names are

> FT_NAME,FC_NAME,C_NAME

and I want to store this values in a data structure for further use, currently I am trying to store them in a list of list but could not do so with following code

```
i=4
    oc=sheet.cell(i,8).value  
    fcl,ocl=[],[]
    while oc:
        ft=sheet.cell(i,6).value
        fc=sheet.cell(i,7).value
        oc=sheet.cell(i,8).value 

        if ft:
            self.foreign_tables.append(ft)
            fcl.append(fc)
            ocl.append(oc)
            self.foreign_col.append(fcl)
            self.own_col.append(ocl)
            fcl,ocl=[],[]

        else:
            fcl.append(fc)
            ocl.append(oc)    

        i+=1
```

i expect output as

```
ft=[FT_NAME1,FT_NAME2,FT_NAME3,FT_NAME4]
fc=[FC1, [FC21,FC22],[FC31,FC32],FC4]
oc=[C1,[C21,C22],[C31,C32],C4]
```

could anyone please help for better pythonic solution ?

Comment: the sublist structure is important? or is it fine also one list for each rows?

Comment: yes its important that's why its complex, otherwise it can be done easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`. It reads the data into a DataFrame which is essentially a big dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

data =pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
data = data.fillna(method='pad')

print(data)
```

it gives the following output:

```
    FT_NAME FC_NAME C_NAME
0  FT_NAME1     FC1     C1
1  FT_NAME2    FC21    C21
2  FT_NAME2    FC22    C22
3  FT_NAME3    FC31    C31
4  FT_NAME3    FC32    C32
5  FT_NAME4     FC4     C4
```

To get the sublist structure try using this function:

```
def group(data):
    output = []
    names = list(set(data['FT_NAME'].values))
    names.sort()
    output.append(names)
    headernames = list(data.columns)
    headernames.pop(0)

    for ci in list(headernames):
        column_group = []
        column_data = data[ci].values
        for name in names:
            column_group.append(list(column_data[data['FT_NAME'].values == name]))
        output.append(column_group)

    return output
```

If you call it like this:

```
ft, fc, oc = group(data)
print(ft)
print(fc)
print(oc)
```

you get the following output:

```
['FT_NAME1', 'FT_NAME2', 'FT_NAME3', 'FT_NAME4']
[['FC1'], ['FC21', 'FC22'], ['FC31', 'FC32'], ['FC4']]
[['C1'], ['C21', 'C22'], ['C31', 'C32'], ['C4']]
```

which is what you want except for the single element now also being in a list.

It is not the cleanest method but it gets the job done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is not I want , sorry, its like if any of the ft_name is missing I want list of FC_NAMES associated with it in a group for example                                      FT_NAME2   ---> [FC21,   FC22]

Comment: thanks for the effort but actually I don't have the liberty to use pandas here just using xlrd and also FT_NAMES are not filled when its grouped so every value for FT_NAME is not there, but thanks I will try to make out from your logic